# Fixing obsolete and missing attributes in <object> tag

Tags: html

so I've looked (literally) almost all night trying to figure out how to fix these validation errors I've received through the validator and I don't know how to resolve them:
[image]

And the HTML code:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="533" height="400" id="FlashID" title="Procedures Slides">
  <param name="movie" value="assets/slides.swf">
  <param name="quality" value="high">
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
  <param name="swfversion" value="11.2.0.0">
  <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
  <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf">
  <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
  <!--[if !IE]>-->
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="assets/slides.swf" width="533" height="400">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
    <param name="swfversion" value="11.2.0.0">
    <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf">
    <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
    <div>
      <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
      <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
    </div>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
  </object>
  <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

Comment: Sorry to sound a bit brief, but I'm doing other things at the moment. (1) - Forget validation - does it work in all major browsers? (2) - If it wants a data and type param then provide them. (3) - I've never known browsers to crash if the classid is outdated - it just gets ignored... If no-one else helps you with this, I probably can - I've done it before but forgotten the details. Get back to me if necessary and I'll look it all up.

Comment: Well, I am a little desperate . . . if you can that would be great :)

Comment: OK, I'll get back to you...

Answer (score 0):

OK - start from here... this works for me in all major browsers - and IE8/9 the last time I tried. Although it may not validate (I haven't tried), but it works wherever I try it:

www.ajduffill.org.uk/TD_swf_test.htm

Run this to confirm it works, then download the htm file and use the Object section as a model for your swf file. If it still doesn't work, it may be to do with your file - if you want you can email it to me on email@ajduffill.org.uk

It uses a file called wrox.swf which you can download if you want (also in www.ajduffill.org.uk).

Interestingly, though it works in IE it is considerably slower to start than other browsers??

See how you get on...